# Apache RewriteCond equivalent in Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, nginx-location

I'm new to Nginx, and trying to translate the following rule I have for a WordPress site from Apache to Nginx. I'm starting out with the default Nginx configuration on a Ubuntu machine running Nginx 1.4.6.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/themes/path/to/exclude/file\.php
RewriteRule wp-content/themes/(.*\.php)$ log.php?f=$1 [L]
```

The rule above rewrites all requests to `wp-content/themes/*.php` to `security-log.php`, with the exception of files defined in the the `RewriteCond` rule.

From what I gather, the way to do this in Nginx is to use the `location` block. I've tried the following (I'm still not sure what to do to exclude particular files/folders).

```
location = /wp-content/plugins/(.*\.php)$ {
    try_files /security-log.php =404;
}
```

The above rule seems to be getting ignored entirely (maybe i have something wrong with the regex?).

If I provide a fixed path, as follows, the rule is invoked, but Nginx will serve the PHP file (browser will download the file) rather than execute it using the PHP interpreter (most probably this is because `fast-cgi` is not being called upon).

```
location = /wp-content/plugins/test.php {
    try_files /security-log.php =404;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: did you tried this one: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is invalid syntax for a regex location. It should probably look like this:

```
location ~ ^/wp-content/plugins/.*\.php$ { ... }
```

Rather than a `try_files` directive, you should use `rewrite`, like this:

```
rewrite ^ /security-log.php last;
```

Of course, neither approach matches the function of the `.htaccess` file.

You have already observed that the location block that processes a PHP file must contain the `fastcgi` directives. This can be achieved by placing them into a separate file and using the `include` directive to pull them into multiple `location` blocks.

This means that the `.htaccess` file could be implemented by placing a regex location before the existing `location ~ \.php$` block. For example:

```
location = /wp-content/themes/path/to/exclude/file.php {
    include common-php-directives;
}
location ~ ^/wp-content/themes/.*\.php$ {
    rewrite ^/wp-content/themes/(.*\.php)$ /log.php?f=$1 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include common-php-directives;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax.

Comment: The second rule works, however, the exclusion doesn't seem to be working. My guess is that Nginx is prioritising the second rule before the first.

Comment: Regex locations are ordered so that the first matching location wins. Oops, but there is a typo in the exact match location - the `.` should not be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to read this pitfall doc as new user of nginx https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

and for wordpress setup:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/